# AWS Lambda function to make rest api call to api deployed in EC2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to write an AWS Lambda function using java, that make rest api call to the api which is deployed in EC2 url should be configurable.

Comment: so what have you done so far? whats the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider [AWS API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) as proxy of API in your EC2. [Calling from Lambda to API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-call-api.html)  is easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
const https = require("https");

const handler = async (event) => {
    const data = JSON.stringify({
        todo: "Order pizza",
    });

    const options = {
        hostname: "yourwebsite.com",
        port: 443,
        path: "/todos",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Content-Length": data.length,
        },
    };

    const response = await doRequest(options, data);
    console.log("OTP response", JSON.stringify(response));

    return event;
};

/**
 * Do a request with options provided.
 *
 * @param {Object} options
 * @param {Object} data
 * @return {Promise} a promise of request
 */
function doRequest(options, data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
            res.setEncoding("utf8");
            let responseBody = "";

            res.on("data", (chunk) => {
                responseBody += chunk;
            });

            res.on("end", () => {
                resolve(JSON.parse(responseBody));
            });
        });

        req.on("error", (err) => {
            reject(err);
        });

        req.write(data);
        req.end();
    });
}

module.exports = {
    handler,
};
```